# concatenating lists in a pandas dataframe and getting the unique tokens in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame consisting of 4 columns the first one is ID, and the other columns have lists as their values in each row. i need to concatenate all these three columns and take the unique tokens and create another column. this is one row and i have a bit more than 1 million records.

```
original_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':1, 
                   'Name_List1':[[ 'aa','bb']],
                   'Name_List2':[['Mutiso','Julia','Linger']],
                  'Name_List3':[['Mutiso','Julia','Linger','bb','cc']]})
```

and the desired df is something output of this script

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':1, 
                   'Name_List1':[[ 'aa','bb']],
                   'Name_List2':[['Mutiso','Julia','Linger']],
                  'Name_List3':[['Mutiso','Julia','Linger','bb','cc']],
                  'Unique_name_list':[['aa','bb','cc','Mutiso','Julia','Linger']]})
```

How can i get the 5th column that is "Unique_name_list" column

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) , [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)(Note this is new in pandas 0.25+)  and [`groupby+agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) , then `map`

```
m = original_df.set_index('ID').stack().explode()
       .drop_duplicates().groupby(level=0).agg(list)
original_df['Unique_name_list'] = original_df['ID'].map(m)
print(original_df)
```

---

```
   ID Name_List1               Name_List2                       Name_List3  \
0   1   [aa, bb]  [Mutiso, Julia, Linger]  [Mutiso, Julia, Linger, bb, cc]   

                      Unique_name_list  
0  [aa, bb, Mutiso, Julia, Linger, cc]
```

---

Or (slower version)

You can try `apply` with `np.concatenate` and `set`:

```
original_df = original_df.set_index('ID')
final = original_df.assign(Unique_name_list=original_df.apply(lambda x : 
                          [*set(np.concatenate(x))],axis=1)).reset_index()
```

---

```
   ID Name_List1               Name_List2                       Name_List3  \
0   1   [aa, bb]  [Mutiso, Julia, Linger]  [Mutiso, Julia, Linger, bb, cc]   

                      Unique_name_list  
0  [bb, Mutiso, cc, aa, Julia, Linger]
```